# SFML Space Invaders : Updating ScoreSystem with text issue

Tags: c++, sfml

I created a text class which stores all necessary values for text. I'm having problems with the text variable of points updating and not sure how I can fix the issue.

I believe it's because i'm storing the points variable into the text vector and push it back so it never gets updated. Im wondering how I can go around this as I'm struggling to find a solution! Apologies for my code I am a complete noob.

Text.cpp

```
Text::Text(float positionX, float positionY, unsigned int fontSize, std::string text, sf::Color textColour)
{
    //Load Font
    if(!textFont.loadFromFile("fonts/unifont.ttf"))
    {
        std::cout << "Error loading unifont.ttf fonts" << std::endl;
    }
    
    this->text.setFont(textFont);
    this->text.setPosition(positionX, positionY);
    this->text.setCharacterSize(fontSize);
    this->text.setString(text);
    this->text.setFillColor(textColour);
    this->text.setOrigin(this->text.getGlobalBounds().width / 2, this->text.getGlobalBounds().height / 2);
}

//render text
void Text::renderTo(sf::RenderWindow* target)
{
    target->draw(text);
}
```

Game.cpp

```
void Game::initText()
{
    updateText(); 
    this->texts.push_back(new Text(140, 0, 60, ssScore.str(), sf::Color(255, 255, 255)));
    
}

//Update Text
void Game::updateText()
{
    ssScore << "Points: " << points; //displays 0 but does not update when points variable updates.
}

//Text Render
for(auto *text : this->texts)
{
    text->renderTo(window);
}
```

Game.h

```
std::ostringstream ssScore;
std::vector<Text*> texts;
```

Comment: sfml has a built-in text class https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Text.php

Comment: @Yamahari I am aware of this, I created a text class initially to prevent me from rewriting code so it looks cleaner. I was wondering if theres a way to implement the score system using my text class, if not then I will just use sfml built-in text class.

Comment: It looks to me that you do not update the `Text` object when you update the points. Presumably `updateText()` is meant to do that, but it just appends the score to an unrelated `ssScore`. You use `ssScore` when creating the Text object, but `sf::Text` stores its own string, not a reference. You could create a `setString()` function in the `Text` class, then call it in `updateText()`. If you are using `ssScore` then you should also call `ssScore.clear()` to clear the string stream.

Comment: As @Lily pointed, you are not updating the string of your text object, which you might wanna do whenever the score changes or every frame (Replace, don't append). Adding to this, if you do want to use a class for your specific use case you can try making your text class as a child to SFML's text class. That will handle most of the issues and reduce the effort of writing same code again and again.